# How to change youtube display language without cookies?

Tags: php, youtube

```
$site = file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/@PewDiePie");
```

I'm pulling data from youtube with `file_get_contents`. but since the language setting and IP address of my hosting service are Turkey, when I use `file_get_contents`, a Turkish page appears.

How can I view the content in English?

Comment: The `Accept-Language` header. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `hl` in your URL's query string.

In below example I used `hl=en` for English language!\

The `persist_hl=1` is for preserving language after redirection!

```php
$site = file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/@PewDiePie?hl=en&persist_hl=1");
```

Answer (score 2):

This solved my problem:

```
$newurl="https://www.youtube.com/@PewDiePie";
$opts = [
    "http" => [
    "method" => "GET",
        "header" => "Accept-language: en\r\n" .
            "Cookie: hl=en\r\n"    ]];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents("$newurl", false, $context);
echo "$file";
```